# What is the function of the RF pulse in NMR?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, spectroscopy, atoms, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am slightly confused about the purpose of the RF (radiofrequency) pulse in NMR. The powerpoint of my course mentioned that an RF pulse perturbs the equilibrium magnetization and sets the nucleus into precession. My understanding however, was that the RF pulse was meant to flip an already precessing nucleus to create a current in the coil, and not to induce the precession itself?

Comment: Can you clarify in the question if you are interested in a classical description or in a full quantum mechanical description?

Comment: A classical description would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

In general, the magnetization vector can be broken into a component, $M_z$, that is parallel to the static magnetic field, $B_0$, and a component, $M_{xy}$, that is perpendicular to $B_0$. Precession at the Larmor frequency only causes the $M_{xy}$ component to change, not the $M_z$ component. It is precisely the changing of the $M_{xy}$ component at the Larmor frequency that induces a voltage in the RF receive coil.

When the spins are fully relaxed $M_{xy}=0$, so there is no precession and therefore no RF signal. There is not an already precessing magnetization vector. Instead, the purpose of the RF pulse is as the PowerPoint described: to perturb the fully relaxed state and convert some of the $M_z$ into $M_{xy}$.

Once the RF transmit pulse has produced some $M_{xy}$ then the $B_0$ field immediately makes it precess at the Larmor frequency. (That is why the Larmor frequency depends on the main magnetic field strength.) It is this precessing $M_{xy}$ which then produces the signal measured in the RF receive coil.

Comment: Thank you so much!